# Pass JSON array from a controller to a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a JSON array from a database and I have it set up in a controller like so:

```
public ActionResult highlight()
{
    var statesHighlight =
        db.Jobs
            .Select(r => r.State);
    return Json(statesHighlight , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How do I set this as a JavaScript variable in my view? I'm sure there's a simple way, but I can't seem to figure it out. Do I use @Html.Action or @Url.Action?

EDIT:
Here's how I currently have my data hard coded for the plugin I'm using:

```
<script type="application/json" id="map-data">
    ["CA","UT","FL","MT","WA","KS","KS","UT"]
</script>

<script>
    var data = $.parseJSON($('#map-data').text());
    var cities = $.parseJSON($('#city-data').text());


    $('img').mapster({
        mapKey: 'state',
        clickNavigate: true,
        isSelectable: false,
        highlight: false,
        onConfigured: function () {

            // make the array into a comma-sparated list
            var csv = data.join(',');

            var city_list = cities.join(',');

            // the 'set' activates the areas
            $('img').mapster('set', true, csv, options = { fillColor: '638EA5' });
            //altImage: '../Images/map_outline_blackStrokeDot.png'
            $('img').mapster('set', true, city_list, options = { fillColor: 'ffffff' });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this being returned to an ajax call?

Comment: No, I'm using the data for a plugin called ImageMapster to highlight areas on an image map.

Comment: I don't know anything about that plugin but you need to make that clear in the question and show the relevant scripts you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('gimmearray'
            , null
            , function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    });
</script>
```

And the controller:

```
    public JsonResult GimmeArray()
    {
        string[] theArray = {"this", "is", "an", "array"};

        return Json(theArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

On you controller, you probably have to execute that query using `ToArray`.